# python:organising a text file of users scores into a list

Tags: python

I have this text file containing something like this:

```
John = 10
Lucy = 2
Tom = 4,
Hardy = 7
tom = 5
tom = 3
hardy = 7
Christoper = 4
Kim = 9
Tom = 4
john = 5 
John = 7
John = 6
```

I need to read this file and organize it into a list however only using the last three scores of the users. I have been trying for hours but cant get it working, please help thankyou

Comment: If you split the lines on the = sign, you'll have name, score pairs.

Comment: Are  the names case sensitive?

Comment: i orginally tried somthing like this                                                                                                                 for line in f:
            column = line.split("=")
            scores = column[1]
            name = column[0].strip()
            score = int(column[1].strip())
            if name == name:
                high_score = name, score, score
                    
   
   
            else:
                high_score =name, score
                results.append(high_score)
                        print(name)
            names.append(name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
dic={}

with open("demo.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b=line.strip().replace(" ","").split("=")
            if a.lower() in dic:
                dic[a.lower()].append(b)
            else:
                dic[a.lower()]=[]
                dic[a.lower()].append(b)


for d in dic:
    dic[d]= dic[d][-3:]

print dic
```

Output:

```
{'christoper': ['4'], 'lucy': ['2'], 'hardy': ['7', '7'], 'kim': ['9'], 'tom': ['5', '3', '4'], 'john': ['5', '7', '6']}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store this file in a dictionary in Python. The key to your dictionary can be the name of the individuals. The value for your key can be a list, where you will store the respective scores. Every time, you see a score for a person, you can **append** it to the end of the list. Once you are done parsing, you will find the last 3 scores of a person at the end of their respective lists. You can extract them by calling the **pop** operation thrice on the list.

Comment: hi, thankyou for your response, yes this sounds about righ, could you perhaps share how i could about actually coding this as i have not dealt with dictionaries before.